# Mixed model weight matrix

Tags: mixed-model, mathematical-statistics

Consider Henderson’s classic mixed model equations:

[image]

What is the nature of the weight matrix, S-1?  I believe that this is composed of the covariance matrix, but at the same time it is diagonal.  How can that work?  If X is 100 X 5, then S-1 is necessarily 100 X 100.  However, the covariance matrix is 5 X 5.  Does this mean that S-1 has a series of 5 X 5 matrices on the diagonal? If the off-diagonal elements are zero, then are they all 5 X 5 matrices?  If this is correct, how does the multiplication work?

Comment: $S$ is indeed the variance-covariance matrix of the outcomes. However, what makes you think it is diagonal? And if $X$ is $100 \times 5$, then indeed $S$ (and hence $S^{-1}$) is $100 \times 100$. And then $X'S^{-1}X$ is $5 \times 5$. There is nothing special going on here.

Comment: @Wolfgang I figured this out over the weekend.  S is composed of the variances of within the subject blocks.  As such, it varies in size.  The v option on the random statement in SAS will recover the matrix.  It is not a diagonal matrix as you say.  For my purposes it will be, however, since I'm interested in computing a specialized IC.  Should have been more clear about that.  My bad.

Comment: No, Henderson gave his equations in a completely general form for the *entire* vector of the outcomes, not a subset of them. There may be 'blocks of subjects', but maybe there are not. Therefore, $S$ is the *entire* variance-covariance matrix of the outcomes and it doesn't "vary in size" (there is just *one* $S$). And I never said that $S$ is block-diagonal. It often is (when indeed there are 'blocks of subjects' and we assume independence between subjects), but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the nature of the weight matrix, S-1? I believe that this is composed of the covariance matrix,

Not "composed" of. It is the variance covariance matrix.

> but at the same time it is diagonal.

No, it will be square.

> If X is 100 X 5, then S-1 is necessarily 100 X 100.

Yes.

> However, the covariance matrix is 5 X 5.

No. It's 100 x 100 so if X has dimension 100 x 5 the dimension of $X'S^{-1}X$ is (5 x 100) (100 x 100) (100 x 5) which will be 5 x 5